# Can we override dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) in fragment?

Tags: android

When i am overriding this method in fragment then it is showing error like

**The method dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent) is undefined for the type Fragment**

This is my fragment i have created.....

```
public class ChatterContainerFragment extends Fragment implements
        SimpleGestureListener {
}
```

in this i am trying to override...

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        // Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class
        this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
}
```

When I am overriding in FragmentActivity then its working fine.
But for fragment it is not working.

Please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it,

1) You can add a `TouchListener` on the fragment View after creating the View. That's the most simple way.

2) You know that **Fragments** are attached to the **Activity** so you can override the `dispatchTouchEvent` method in the activity and pass actions from there. Like this,

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT_TAG");
    myFragment.doSomething();

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

**UPDATE**

You need to do this to access a Dragment method from an Activity,

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
fragment.<specific_function_name>();
```

Comment: I tried the second one but I am getting NullPointerException.

Comment: @Override
 public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
  ChatterContainerFragment chatterContainerFragment = (ChatterContainerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentByTag(StockalUtility.MAIN_FRAGMENT);
  chatterContainerFragment.dispatchEvent(ev);
  return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
 }

Comment: I have overriden this method in MainActivity and from dispatchTouchEvent(), I am calling fragment method as you told. but getting exception

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.stockal, PID: 5795
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.stockal.ChatterContainerFragment.dispatchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)' on a null object reference
at com.stockal.MainActivity.dispatchTouchEvent(MainActivity.java:53)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8583)

Comment: I have declared specific_function_name inside fragment class, and calling that method from MainActivity using fragment.<specific_function_name>();. But getting NullPointerException

Comment: Yes, because you are not accessing the fragment properly. Use findFragmentById().

Comment: Actually I have one MainActivity and in this i am using one fragment. Now again i am inflating another fragment inside the first fragment. My first fragment is implementing SimpleGestureListener, and having ViewPager in xml. I want to slide the second fragment, so the dispatchTouchEvent() will call, and for that i have to override this method in first fragment because i am implementing SimpleGestureListener inside first fragment. Please help me on this how i can override...

Comment: I have told you to use findFragmentByTag(). You are not willing to use it. If you want to use findFragmentByTag then you need to use the exact same TAG that you used while adding the fragment.